# parse.com set undefined to date field in data browser

Tags: date, parse-platform, undefined

How can I set undefined or null and make empty to a date field in the parse.com data browser.

There is nothing related with code, in the pic i attached, you can see the parse.com data browser and i want to set undefined or null whatever and make that field empty but whenever i tried and double click the cell, data browser open date widget and it is not allowed to delete the data or there is no button to make empty.

[Parse.com Data Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAAAj.png)

Comment: did you try double-clicking and deleting?

Comment: could you explain a bit more and maybe add some code so it is possible to see what might be causing it?

Comment: Good question, I have the same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In data-browser I don't think it's possible to delete a date value, I couldn't find a way to do it at least.

And now that Parse.com will not be maintained anymore(in 01/01/2017 it will shut down), I don't think this may come up as a feature.

My solution to this problem was to make a request to this register and use unset. It gets a bit more of work but solves the problem.

I don't know if you're using parse with Javascript but it can be really easy to adapt to other enviroments.

In Javascript this script should do the trick:

```
var DateUpdate = Parse.Object.extend("MyTableOnParse");
var dateUpdateEdit = new Parse.Query(DateUpdate);
dateUpdateEdit.equalTo("objectId",myObjectId);
dateUpdateEdit.first({
    success: function(object)
    {    
        object.unset("saleDate");
        object.save({
            success: function(updatedObject) 
            {
               console.log("Data deleted");
            }
        })
    }
});
```